# Whats happening If i add key/value pairs to eternal ehcache

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

Assumed that a webapplication uses ehcache. The cache-configuration file (xml) declares a **eternal** cache so the data will never expire. The cache is working but I have additional questions.

What's happening with the eternal cache:

- If I add additional key-value pairs to the cache.
- I I delete specific keys-value paris from the cache.
- If there is an update taken place, what is the interval?